# Absolute path in Linux (with space in file path)

Tags: linux, path, find

So I want to list files with full path in current dir, and if I write

```
find $PWD
```

the thing works but when there is a space in path i.e.:

```
/media/sda3/Music/Dub/Albums/Juakali/2011 - DreadBass Soundsystem
```

`find $PWD` gives me this:

```
find: `/media/sda3/Music/Dub/Albums/Juakali/2011': No such file or directory
find: `-': No such file or directory
find: `DreadBass': No such file or directory
find: `Soundsystem': No such file or directory
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Quote your argument:

```
find "$PWD"
```

Answer (score 2):

$PWD is same as `.`. So you can use

```
find .
```

If it wasn't $PWD you could enclose it with quote `"`

```
find "$VARIABLE"
```

Comment: No, `$PWD` is not `..`.  And why `$PWD` cannot be used with quotes?

Comment: Agree with you. But read my answer carefully. I said `.` **not** `..`

Comment: Oh I see. My screen doesn't show this grey background too well.

Comment: This does *not* answer the question: user1247358 wants to “to list files with full path” (I suspect this means absolute path).